# Trying to render 2d image inside the forge viewer with 3d model

Tags: autodesk-forge

My current use case is to align a 2d image to a 3d model inside the forge viewer allowing zoom as well as panning functionalities. I have tried the following implementations -

1. Adding the 2d image as an overlay scene on the forge viewer but the problem there is that I can't position the model on the image precisely even though i have tried translating, rotating and scaling the model programatically.
2. Loading two different viewers on top of each other and then using `viewer.getState()` and `viewer.restoreState()` to sync the state between the two viewers on `Autodesk.Viewing.CAMERA_CHANGE_EVENT`.
3. Placing the image inside the HTML beneath the forge viewer and then disabling the pointer events on the viewer and using Javascript to zoom both the viewer and the image in sync. But the problem there is that the measure tool doesn't seem to work right.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you simply want to insert a 2D raster image into the viewer scene. That can certainly be done using the 1st approach you suggested. Use an overlay scene or the [SceneBuilder extension](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/scenebuilder-extension-forge-viewer-action) to add a custom three.js mesh into the scene, and then apply your image as a texture to the mesh.

Regarding the placement of the mesh in the viewer scene, that really depends on your use case and the type of models you're working with. For example, if you wanted to place the image under the 3D model (perhaps the picture contains some satellite imagery), you could find the bounding box of the model using the viewer APIs (`viewer.model.getBoundingBox()`), and place the three.js object with your image at the bottom side of it.